# Cron won't execute none of my commands on Ubuntu 21.10 impish

Tags: linux, docker, ubuntu, cron

I'm trying to run a Docker container every other minute that is stopped via cron job but it seems not working.

What I've done is launch the command `crontab -e` and add the line

```
*/1 * * * * docker start sender >> /home/cronlog.log 2>&1
```

I've added the user group to Docker as explained [here](https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/linux-postinstall/) (in fact I can access docker from the terminal without `sudo`)

I have also tried to add the command into a script as below

```
*/1 * * * * /home/start_container.sh >> /home/cronlog.log 2>&1
```

with the script containing

```
#!/bin/sh
docker start sender
```

but still, nothing happens. The cron process is working tho as using the command `ps -ef | grep cron` I got

```
root         881       1  0 08:42 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/cron -f -P
nicola     10905   10178  0 11:31 pts/0    00:00:00 grep --color=auto cron
```

Am I missing something? (Obviously, the commands work if launched manually from the terminal)

Comment: what do you see with  `crontab -l`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that, for some reason, the cron doesn't like the `/home/` (at least, in this specific instance)

I've fixed using another path such as

```
*/1 * * * * docker start sender >> /tmp/cronlog.log 2>&1
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using the docker path instead.

type the following command to get the path of docker.

```sh
$ where docker

/usr/bin/docker
/bin/docker
```

then try any one of the paths in the cron script

```sh
*/1 * * * * /bin/docker start sender >> /home/cronlog.log 2>&1
```

or

```sh
*/1 * * * * /usr/bin/docker start sender >> /home/cronlog.log 2>&1
```